# SQLite VB.net Query

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

im trying to learn coding using VB.net, I have a simple CRUD application(VB.net and Sqlite) where the data is show in a grid box. everything works except the searching of the data.

i want to seach the DB based on the column name in which the user chooses in the combobox.

original code:

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    ' search functions
    connect()
    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_biodata WHERE name like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", connection)
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    da.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    connection.Clone()
    da.Dispose()
End Sub
```

the original code works, but i wanted to have an option to search based on the column name, so i tried this

modified code:

```
   Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    ' search functions
    connect()
    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_biodata WHERE name like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", connection)
    Dim db As New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_biodata WHERE country like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", connection)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    If ComboBox1.SelectedValue = "name" Then
        da.Fill(dt)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedValue = "country" Then
        db.Fill(dt)

    End If


    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    connection.Clone()
    da.Dispose()
End Sub
```

i can't get it to work. i know my main problem is

```
     Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_biodata WHERE name like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", connection)
```

but i got no more idea on how to do it. any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Look into parameterized queries, otherwise you are open to sql injection.

Comment: You say that you can't get it to work. That means that something happens other than what you expect. That means that you know what actually happens. Why don't we know that?

Comment: Why create two data adapters if you know that you'll only use one? At least put the creation of the data adapter into the `If...Else` block so you only create what you need. Better still would be that you just insert the selected value directly into the SQL code and then just go ahead and create the one and only data adapter.

Comment: @jmcilhiney that's actually what i need but i don't know how to do it. i tried this    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_biodata WHERE 'combobox1.selectedvalue' like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", connection)  but it's giving me a blank result in each of the selected value.

Comment: Initialise each adapter in the actual `IF` statement rather than outside. As it stands you're creating both and only need one. Use parameters. Also debug your code and make sure `SelectedValue` is what you think it is. And lastly _close_ your connection don't _clone_.

Comment: @Bugs i already try initializing the adapter inside an IF statement. but it's giving me an error "da is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level"  that's why i was interested in jmcilhinney's suggestion that "insert the selected value directly into the SQL code but i have no idea on how to do that. also i tried the selectedtext and selectedvalue both are giving blank result.

Comment: You would have the same code in both `IF` statements but different queries. `Dim da As New...` and then `da.Fill`. It needs to be in both but it's only initialised once. And I think the problem lies with `SelectedValue` being blank and so no adapter is filled. We would need to see how you're filling the `ComboBox1` items. Please edit your question to show that. And I'm not entire sure what @jmcilhinney means.

Comment: You dont need to (re) create DataAdapters and/or (re)fill tables.  You can simply filters to a DataTable - that requires not using just local objects though

Comment: @bugs ok i will try to put the dim da and the da.fill inside the if statement, the one i tried is only put the dim as new inside the if statement and was giving me an error.

Comment: @Plutonix could you please show how is that done? but i can't get it to work. i tried this 
 Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter
if combobox1.selectedvalue = "name" then
da = "SELECT * FROM tbl_biodata WHERE name like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", connection"
end if
but i was having an error in the da = "select...." it seems that i cannot use the ", connection"  without that it wont run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Answer, thank you everyone for the Help

```
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_biodata WHERE name like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", connection)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        connection.Close()
        da.Dispose()
    Else
        Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_biodata WHERE country like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", connection)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        connection.Close()
        da.Dispose()

    End If
```